# Broken link after deploying asp.net web application IIS7

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, deployment, iis-7

I have my web_app that i want to deploy under the existing domain.it/

The problem is that all urls in the web_app are absolute,  so all the links are broken.

How i can say, is it possible, for iis to change the root level of the web_app?
I can't deploy web_app folder under root.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you use path in such a way, then you don't need to care where your application will be deployed. look below some example....

```
<img alt="" runat="server" src="~/Images/abc.jpg" />
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
```

`~` Will map to Application Root Directory

Comment: yes for server tag no problem...the problem is that i have a lot of html link in <a href="/subfolder_web_app/..."> and / point to root/web_app so all link are broken....

Comment: You can put runat="server" to make server control. Then it will work.

Comment: in this way i have to edit all pages of my web_app. however and i have also a lot of jquery that point #clientid. if i put runat="server" maybe the id of html element will change and i lost functionally...